# How can I define the equality of pair in Coq?

Tags: coq

I define a type as follows:

```
Definition trans := env -> env -> Prop.
Definition tripored := trans * trans * trans.
Definition qt (t : tripored) := fst (fst t).
Definition wt (t : tripored) := snd (fst t).
Definition tt (t : tripored) := snd t.
Definition II := (ttrue, tfalse, I).
```

Then I define a operator based on the *tripored* such as

```
Definition seqtr (m n : tripored) : tripored :=
(
  nott (ort (nott (qt m)) (dseq (tt m) (nott (qt n)))),
  ort (wt m) (dseq (tt m) (wt n)),
  dseq (tt m) (tt n)
).
```

There are many operators such as *ort*, *dseq* and so on. I want to prove the following theorem:

```
Theorem seqtr_ii :
  forall n : tripored, seqtr n II = n.
```

However, since the **(seqtr n II)** has type **trans * trans * trans**, I find difficult to prove this theorem. Can anyone give some advice for this theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not provide all the definitions, it is hard to answer precisely, but I will try.

Since `n` is a triple, you can first extract its components with `destruct n as ((t1, t2), t3)`, where `t1`, `t2`, `t3` are of type `trans`.

Then `unfold seqtr` replaces `seqtr` with its body.

The conclusion becomes an equality of two triples. To turn it into 3 goals stating the equality of the components, you can use `do 2 apply f_equal2` or just `f_equal`.